# Why returns false without comparison?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log([1,2,3] > null); // returns false

// "1,2,3" > null
// NaN > null
// false => Direct returns false ??
```

The code returns false. Normally NaN > null must be numeric comparison. But result returned false. Why?

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: I know why returns false. But why returns false without comparison. I asked it.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make much sense. What do you mean "without comparison"? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Remember anything compared to `NaN` in any way will **always return false**. Even `NaN === NaN` will do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the steps in the [Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison):

- `[1,2,3] > null` - Step 1 (a,b): Apply ToPrimitive to both sides
- `"1,2,3" > null` - Step 4 (d, e): Apply ToNumeric to both sides

Now we have `NaN > 0`, which is `false`, because any time `NaN` is involved in any relational operation, the result is `false`.

In a comment on the question you asked:

> But why returns false without comparison.

`>` **is** a comparison. I think you mean "without a branching operation or expression" (like `if` or the conditional operator, `? :`). If so, it's because expressions (including relational expressions) have result values whether or not you use those results for branching. The result of a `>` expression is `true` or `false`. If you use that in an `if`, that's fine, but you don't have to:

```
const a = 1 > 2;
console.log(a); // false
```